# Is it possible copy file in the private path to document directory?

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

This is my code.
I used captureVideo() from ionic native mediacapture plugin.

And get this file path

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/95DB5A64-700B-4E3D-9C2C-562C46520BEC/tmp/52515367181__BBC39D42-69EC-4384-A36F-7A512E109329.MOV

I want to copy this file to document directory.

```
CreateVide(){

      //SET CAPTUREVIDOE OPTION
      let videooption:CaptureVideoOptions = {limit:1};

      //CAPTURE VIDEO AND GET MEDIAFILE
      this.mediaCapture.captureVideo().then((videoData:Array<MediaFile>)=>{

        //SAVE AS FILE
          let filedir = this.file.documentsDirectory ;
          //Create directory
          this.file.createDir(filedir,'recordvideo',false);
          //SAVE FILE
          // this.file.writeFile(filedir + 'recordvideo', 'sample.mov', videoData[0]. );
          console.log('success:'+ videoData[0].fullPath);
          var ind = (videoData[0].fullPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
          var orgFilename = videoData[0].fullPath.substring(ind);
          var orgFilePath = videoData[0].fullPath.substring(0,ind);

          console.log(orgFilename, orgFilePath,filedir + 'recordvideo');
          this.file.copyFile(orgFilePath, orgFilename, filedir + 'recordvideo','sample.mov');
      });
}
```

Is it possible?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue on your implementation?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The file isn't copied.

Comment: Are you using any `native plugin`?

Comment: import {MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureVideoOptions} from '@ionic-native/media-capture';

I use this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreateVideo()
  {
      //SET CAPTUREVIDOE OPTION
      let videooption:CaptureVideoOptions = {limit:1};

      //CAPTURE VIDEO AND GET MEDIAFILE
      this.mediaCapture.captureVideo().then((videoData:Array<MediaFile>)=>{

        //SAVE AS FILE
        let filedir = this.file.documentsDirectory ;
        //Create directory
        this.file.createDir(filedir,'recordvideo',false);


        //CHANGE PATH
        var path = videoData[0].fullPath.replace('/private','file://');
        var ind = (path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        var orgFilename = path.substring(ind);
        var orgFilePath = path.substring(0,ind);

        //SAVE FILE                    
        this.file.copyFile(orgFilePath, orgFilename, filedir + 'recordvideo','sample.mov');

      });
  }
```

I solved this program by replacing file path.
Better answer will be appreciated.

Comment: I need to send this captured video as form data to my backend. How can I do that?